# VNC connection failed: Too many security failures

Tags: vnc

I am trying to use VNC to `vnc4server` from the `Remmina` client via an `ssh` tunnel. I establish the `ssh` tunnel with `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 user@remoteIp` I have had successful VNC sessions to this server in the past. However I am now getting an error.

What is the cause of this `Remmina` error message.

`VNC connection failed: Too many security failures`

Does this mean somebody is trying to intrude (hack into) my server?

How would I investigate this? I have a login session which I can use to investigate this because the command to setup the `ssh` tunnel gives me a shell prompt.

Comment: For me I had a VNC connection to a remote Ubuntu machine from a local virtual machine Ubuntu guest, and I performed a "save state" on the VM so the next time I tried to login I got that error. Thus I was added to the VNC blacklist.

Of course you need to investigate why you are getting that error, but if you are sure that it is not a security vulnerability then to re-allow VNC connections and clear the blacklist simply wait a while or stop and restart your vnc server. For details please see https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003563111-Too-Many-Security-Failures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information at this [link](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/244/1/too-many-security-failures) suggests to me that it was an attempt at intrusion. To succeed in establishing a VNC session a legitimate user must wait. In practice waiting a few minutes is necessary before a successful VNC session is allowed once again. There is no need to re-establish the `ssh` tunnel.

Comment: So intruders were able to ssh into the server but failed to log into the VNC server? Sounds like you have more to worry about than just getting logged on.

Comment: @symcbean, I edited to correct the record.